# expression must have pointer type error visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I use visual studio 2012 and when i tried to build this simple program i receive this error and i can't understand where is the problem. Here is my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#define MAXN 400 //max digits
using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    //signbit nqma nujda v tozi slu4ai
    char digits[MAXN];
    int lastdigit;
} BigInteger;

BigInteger addBigIntegers(BigInteger *a, BigInteger *b, BigInteger *c)
{
    c->lastdigit = max(a->lastdigit, b->lastdigit);
    int carry = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<=(c->lastdigit); i++)
    {
        c->digits[i] = (char)(carry + a->digits[i] + b->digits[i]) % 10;
        carry = (carry + a->digits[i] + b->digits[i]) / 10;
    }
    return *c;
}

int main()
{
    BigInteger a;
    BigInteger b;
    string input1;
    string input2;
    cin >> input1 >> input2;
    int len1 = input1.length();
    int len2 = input2.length();
    for(int i = len1-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
         a->digits[i] = 5;
    }
}
```

The error is on this line:

```
a->digits[i] = 5;
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: `a` isn't a pointer. `operator->` requires a pointer or a class that overloads it.

Comment: I changed it to a.digits[i] and now it is working fine. Thnx a lot.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, `object->member` is syntactic sugar for `(*object).member`. That is, it *dereferences* `object` before attempting to access `member`. The dereferencing operator `*` can only be applied to pointer types.

N.B. There are exceptions to this - if `object` is an instance of a class which overloads either `*` or `->`, these operators will perform their function as defined in the class. In this case, it is possible to apply these operators to non-pointer objects.

In general, if you want to access a member of a struct or class, use `object.member`. If you have a pointer to a struct or class, use `(*pointer).member`, or the shorter `pointer->member`.

Also, `typedef struct` is more C than C++. It is more usual to simply declare as `struct` in C++. So the `BigInteger` declaration would become:

```
struct BigInteger {
    char digits[MAXN];
    int lastdigit;
};
```

A `struct` in C++ is just a class where all members are `public` by default.

Comment: "In C++, `object->member` is syntactic sugar for `(*object).member`." If `object` is a pointer, yes; but it's worth noting that `object` may also be an instance of a user-defined type (e.g. a `class`) that overloads `operator->()` (examples are container iterators, smart pointers...). Likewise, "The dereferencing operator `*` can only be applied to pointer types" or to types that overload it.

Comment: Good point - I didn't think of that! I will edit the answer. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer :

```
a.digits[i] = 5;
```

Comment: I'd rather have the long answer please. :)

Comment: What if I'm already using a dot and it says "expression must have pointer type"? I am trying to access a member on a struct instanced like this `git_status_list status_list;` where `git_status_list` is the struct type, and then the expression to access it looks like `status_list.` and it gives the error.